# Scala Parallel Sort Using java.util.Arrays and scala.concurrent.ops.par

Tags: java, scala, sorting, parallel-processing

I think I have implemented some of my code wrong.  I cannot figure out why my sort (using arrays.sort) is taking longer in the "parallel" version than in the non-parallel version (it's obviously in putting the two arrays back together, but I didn't think it would add that much more time on).  If someone could point out any mistakes that I am making or any tips to improve the parallel version over the non-parallel version I would appreciate it.  Am I able to do the array merge more efficiently, or maybe even in parallel?  If so, what is the best practice for implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.collection._

trait Sorts {
  def doSort(a: Array[Double]): Array[Double]
}

object Simple extends Sorts {
  def doSort(a: Array[Double]) = {
    Arrays.sort(a)
    a
  }
}

object Parallel extends Sorts {
  def doSort(a: Array[Double]) = {
    val newArray = new Array[Double](a.length)
    val aLength = (a.length)
    val aSplit = ((a.length / 2).floor).toInt
    ops.par(Arrays.sort(a, 0, aSplit), Arrays.sort(a, (aSplit + 1), aLength))
    def merge(w: Int, x: Int, y: Int) {
      var i = w
      var j = x
      var k = y
      while (i <= aSplit && j <= aLength) {
        if (a(i) <= a(j)) {
          newArray(k) = a(i)
          i = i + 1
        } else {
          newArray(k) = a(j)
          j = j + 1
        }
        k = k + 1
      }
      if (i < aSplit) {
        for (i <- i until aSplit) {
          newArray(k) = a(i)
          k = k + 1
        }
      } else {
        for (j <- j until aLength) {
          newArray(k) = a(j)
          k = k + 1
        }
      }
    }
    merge(0, (aSplit + 1), 0)
    newArray
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val simpleNumbers = Array.fill(10000)(math.random)
    println(simpleNumbers.toList + "\n")
    val simpleStart = System.nanoTime()
    Simple.doSort(simpleNumbers)
    val simpleEnd = System.nanoTime()
    println(simpleNumbers.toList + "\n")
    val simpleDifference = ((simpleEnd - simpleStart) / 1e9).toDouble

    val parallelNumbers = Array.fill(10000)(math.random)
    println(parallelNumbers.toList + "\n")
    val parallelStart = System.nanoTime()
    Parallel.doSort(parallelNumbers)
    val parellelEnd = System.nanoTime()
    println(parallelNumbers.toList + "\n")
    val parallelDifference = ((parellelEnd - parallelStart) / 1e9).toDouble

    println("\n Simple Time Taken: " + simpleDifference + "\n")
    println("\n Parallel Time Taken: " + parallelDifference + "\n")

  }
}
```

Output on an Intel Core i7:

```
Simple Time Taken: 0.01314
Parallel Time Taken: 0.05882
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've got a couple of different things going on here. First, on my system the `ops.par(Arrays.sort(...))` line *by itself* takes longer than all of `Simple.doSort()`. So there must be some overhead (thread creation?) that dominates the performance gain for a smallish array. Try it for 100,000 or a million elements. Second, `Arrays.sort` is an in-place sort, so it doesn't have to incur the cost of creating a new 10k element array for the results.

To avoid creating the second array, you can do the partition first and then sort the two halves in parallel, as [recommended here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Parallelization)

```
def doSort(a: Array[Double]) = {
  val pivot = a(a.length-1)
  var i = 0
  var j = a.length-2
  def swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
    val temp = a(i)
    a(i) = a(j)
    a(j) = temp
  }
  while(i < j-1) {
   if(a(i) <= pivot) {
    i+=1
   }
   else {
    swap(i,j)
    j-=1
   }
  }
  swap(j-1, a.length-1)
  ops.par(Arrays.sort(a,0,a.length/2), Arrays.sort(a,a.length/2+1,a.length))
  a
}
```

After upping the array size to 100k, I do see the parallel version performing around twice as fast on an Intel E5300 CPU.